# Snowpack multi-page application with svelte and tailwindcsss

Tags: frontend, tailwind-css, svelte-3, snowpack

I was able to partially setup the rollup + svelte + tailwind + multi-page , but its slow and debugging is difficult.

though there is svelte + snowpack +  tailwindcss is there here https://github.com/agneym/svelte-tailwind-snowpack

but multi-page snowpack is what i cannot figure out. **I cannot even find any documentation for multi-page snowpack setup.**

Can anyone help me in figuring out how to setup Snowpack + Svelte + **multi-page** + Tailwind-css ?

Answer (score 1):

snowpack.config.mjs:

```
export default {
  mount: {
    public: "/",
    src: "/dist"
  },
...
```

So, all file in `src` will compile to `dist`.

In `/src`, setup an other `page.js` exactly like the `index.js`(if you like, you can only change the import path).

The `Page.svelte` imported in `page.js` will serve as another route aside from `index`.

In `/public`:

Pay attention to the `<script>` tag in `index.html`:
`<script type="module" src="/dist/index.js"></script>`

Now, create another `/public/page.html`, but use the new `page.js`:
`<script type="module" src="/dist/page.js"></script>`

And, that it. You have a new `page` route.